# Flutter multiple notifyListeners calls

Tags: flutter, user-interface, changenotifier

I use notifyListeners from ChangeNotifier in flutter. What happens if I call `notifyListeners()` three times in a row? How many times will the UI be updated in this case?

`notifyListeners` сall code:

```
class Data with ChangeNotifier
{
  String _data = 'some text';
  String get getData => _data;
  void changeString(String newString)
  {
    _data = newString;
    notifyListeners();
    notifyListeners();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The usage:

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newData) => context.read<Data>().changeString(newData),
    );
  }
}
```

Widget tree (if it's important):

`MyTextField` is child of `Widget2`.

`Widget2` is child of `Widget1`.

`Widget1` is child of `HomePage`.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(child: Text(context.watch<Data>().getData),),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Widget1(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UI will only update once. You can test this by simply printing something inside the build method when the `notifyListeners()` is called 3 times or more. The reason the UI is not updated even though notify is called 3 times is because of flutter. Flutter only updates the widget tree if the data in the tree is different from the new data coming in. So even though `notifyListeners()` is called 1000 times, if the current widget tree is the same as before notify was called, flutter doesn't update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

See my [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533330/how-to-combine-features-of-futureprovider-futurebuilder-waiting-for-async-data) in which I have a scenario, where I call `notifyListeners()` twice in one method (and it works).

1. The first time I call it is to show a loading screen in the UI while waiting for async data.
2. The second time I call it is to display the async data once it's ready.